# Azure Powershell: Get objects where property exists in an Array

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell, azure-resource-manager

I am trying to get all vm's where the vm resource group name is in the $rgs array

```
$rgs = (Get-AzureRMResourceGroup | Where-Object { $_.Tags.Keys -eq 'FindMe' }).ResourceGroupName
$vms = (Get-AzureRmVm | Where-Object {$_.ResourceGroupName (Enter logic here) })
foreach ($vm in $vms)
{
    Write-Host $vm
}
```

Is this possible? Or a better way of doing it without creating nested loops?

Comment: `$vms = (Get-AzureRmVm | Where-Object {$_.ResourceGroupName -in $rgs})`

Answer (score 0):

As Matt said, we can use this PS script to get the VM in the array:

```
PS C:\> $b
GROUP
GROUP1
PS C:\>  (Get-AzureRmVm | Where-Object {$b -contains $_.ResourceGroupName})


ResourceGroupName Name Location      VmSize OsType    NIC ProvisioningState
----------------- ---- --------      ------ ------    --- -----------------
GROUP              vm1   eastus Standard_A1  Linux vm1619         Succeeded
GROUP              vm2   eastus Standard_A1  Linux vm2346         Succeeded
GROUP1             vm3   eastus Standard_A1  Linux vm3554         Succeeded
PS C:\> $vms = (Get-AzureRmVm | Where-Object {$b -contains $_.ResourceGroupName})

PS C:\> $vms

ResourceGroupName Name Location      VmSize OsType    NIC ProvisioningState
----------------- ---- --------      ------ ------    --- -----------------
GROUP              vm1   eastus Standard_A1  Linux vm1619         Succeeded
GROUP              vm2   eastus Standard_A1  Linux vm2346         Succeeded
GROUP1             vm3   eastus Standard_A1  Linux vm3554         Succeeded
```

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let me know if you would like further assistance.